# Combine rows by dynamic column names

Tags: sql

I have searched all over and I can't find a the right way to do this, its been 2 weeks and I think its time to ask for help :)

Okay so I have a table with 5 fields CASUAL, DAY, PROD_ID, CUST_ID, ROUTE_ID.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '1'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS sun_draw,
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '2'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS mon_draw,
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '3'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS tues_draw,
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '4'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS wed_draw,           
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '5'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS thur_draw,          
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '6'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS fri_draw,
        CASE
            WHEN DAY = '7'
                 THEN CASUAL
            ELSE '0' END AS sat_draw,   PROD_ID,
    CUST_ID
FROM
    SUPPLIES 
WHERE
    PUBDATE BETWEEN DATEADD( DAY, - 7, GETDATE( ) ) 
    AND GETDATE( ) 
    AND CASUAL > 0 
    AND CUST_ID = 17259
```

And it outputs this

[query results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yih6x.png)

The client asked me to combine the days CASUAL by ROUTE_ID, CUST_ID and PROD_ID

Comment: A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data _and_ the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links). Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Looks like you want an aggregation (GROUP BY). Consult your DBMS manuals it's  straightforward.